# UIPage Control custom style NatGeo

Tags: xcode, ios7, uipagecontrol

In my app I have UIView that flow through the use of a horizontal scrollView. To scroll the view I used the classimo method `[self addChildViewController: [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @ "name Storyboard ID"]];`

Each UIView is followed through the use of UIPageControl classic, but I do not like it and so I wanted to create something like this (see photo)

as you can see from the images above application there is a menu with a triangle pointing down, Indicating the page, passing from one topic to another user through the horizontal swipe on the scrollView

In other words, instead of having the classic shot for the management of the pages, the National Geographic has used a triangle pointing down and the title of the page on which the user is ...

Could someone help me understand how can 'be created a similar PageControl?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of approaches to implement this. Maybe the custom `PageControl` won't be the subclass of a `UIPageControl`.
For example, you can subclass a `UIView`, and put a `UIScrollView` in it. And then put a bunch of `UIButton`s in a row into the `UIScrollView`, each of them has a title that is your page's title. When you tap a button ( you can get this event by `UIButton`'s `-addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`), you can scroll the tapped button to the right position, highlight it, and put a little triangle below it.
There are many possibilities. Say, you can replace the buttons with `UILabel` and add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to capture the users tap, or you can replace the `UIScrollView` with `UITableView` if you get a long list of pages(Of course that will introduce some complexity). You just need to pick your favorite and try it out.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer ... these ideas are perfect ... I noticed that it might be possible to implement a custom control segment to achieve this effect, the problem 'that I could not find the right way to change viewcontroller with an animation that resembles the mode 'push used by navBar. the net I could not even find any tutorials on this page change with the segmented control. Everything 'and find out that' only the classical change of control segment between two viewcontroller but nothing that assimigli to change the animation type vuewcontroller with pushviewcontroller

Comment: I'm not quite understand your usage scenario, maybe post some code will help. In the National Geographic example, I see all the pages looks similar and I think it's reasonable to implements it with a `UIViewController` subclass managing a bunch of pages views. So it's easy to animate between each view using `[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:]`. However, you might want to implement it with a `UIViewController` manage only one page and they are all settled in a container view controller. That's not a different story. There are no animations for view controller per se.

Comment: For instance, you have a rootViewController as the container view controller which has an ivar `_controllers` that hold several `UIViewController` subclasses each of them manages a `pageView`. All the animation tricks are to arrange the frames of these `pageView`s and perform a push effect. You get the adjacent controllers in `_controllers` array, get their `pageView`s, properly set the views frames and animation them. The only difference is that you should manage the view controller life cycles yourself, probably by using `-addChildViewController:` and `-removeFromParentViewController`