# UIScrollView Pagination with header

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, pagination

I would like to create a scrolling page view in storyboard like the Fotmob App. See image below. (scrolling pages and scrolling headers as well)

I have followed https://github.com/TomThorpe/UIScrollSlidingPages which is very good yet i seem to get a bizarre error after moving it into a storyboard app.

Here is the error:

```
[pagesViewController titleForSlidingPagesViewController:atIndex:]: unrecognized         selector sent to instance 0x8e22750
```

Here is a piece of the code (with the error being triggered at the *title variable - .... the variable numOfPages works absolutely fine however):

```
 //get the number of pages
int numOfPages = [self.dataSource numberOfPagesForSlidingPagesViewController:self];

//keep track of where next to put items in each scroller
int nextXPosition = 0;
int nextTopScrollerXPosition = 0;


//loop through each page and add it to the scroller
for (int i=0; i<numOfPages; i++){
    //top scroller (nav) add----

    TTSlidingPageTitle *title = [self.dataSource titleForSlidingPagesViewController:self atIndex:i];
    UIView *topItem;
    if (title == nil){
```

A very similar question has been asked here [UIPage Control custom style NatGeo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468679/uipage-control-custom-style-natgeo)
.....Answer Pending

Does anyone know of other examples I could familiarise myself with or maybe can assist me with what i have.

[image: fotmob]
https://github.com/TomThorpe/UIScrollSlidingPages

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I made some delete action in the function without noticing. This solves the error above

I am still interested in any other work relating to the scrolling pages with storyboard as above. I have done a lot of searching and have found just the one resource

Thanks